# Unresolved external symbol cv::waitKey

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Работаю с OpenCV в среде MSVC2017.

В программе присутствует вызов:

```
keyPressed = cv::waitKey(1)
```

При компиляции ошибка линковки:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)"
```

Какую библиотеку (.lib-файл) нужно добавить, чтобы `waitKey` слинковалась?

И вообще, где искать, какие lib'ы нужны для каких функций OpenCV? По некоторым это легко гуглится (несколько я сам нашёл), а вот по, например, waitKey не нашлось. Или может правильно будет при работе с OpenCV сразу пачку lib'ов подключить? Какой тогда список, чтобы уже все функции нормально работали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим официальную [документацию](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7), где написано, что объявление функции лежить в инклюде `#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>`. В `opencv` есть соответствующий модуль `highgui`, библиотека должна называться соответствующим образом. Но вообще, я бы посоветовал изучить систему сборки `cmake`, которая кросплатформенна, IDE независима и, фактически, стала стандартом. `OpenCV` поддерживает ее.